# Can I retrieve data from multiple tables without duplicated data or multiple queries?

Tags: postgresql, jdbc

Let's say I have tables `companies` and `employees`, where the latter has a `company_id` field referencing the former. I want to know everything about a company with a given ID and the people who work there. I see two ways to do this but both have problems.

I can get all the data in one go with a join:

```
SELECT *
FROM companies, employees
WHERE <id> = companies.id
  AND <id> = employees.company_id
```

but then all the data from a single row in the `companies` table gets repeated in every row in the result (i.e. once for every employee of the company). Conceivably a client could apply some sort of compression or clever analysis to reduce the amount of transmitted data but I don't know if this is actually done or how effective it is.

I can use two queries:

```
SELECT *
FROM companies
WHERE <id> = companies.id

SELECT *
FROM employees
WHERE <id> = employees.company_id
```

but having to make two trips to the database increases lag.

Is there any way around these inefficiencies? I'm using PostgreSQL, Slick (Scala), and Play. Does the JDBC avoid duplicating data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the easiest way to do this is to aggregate all the employee data into an array or a json value which gets appended to the columns of the company. For `jsonb`:

```
SELECT c.*, e.employee_data
FROM companies c
JOIN (
  SELECT company_id, jsonb_agg(to_jsonb(employees)) AS employee_data
  FROM employees
  GROUP BY company_id) e ON e.company_id = c.id
WHERE <id> = companies.id;
```